# Set Angle of Series marks not working

Tags: activex, teechart

I was using Teechart2012.ocx before this function Series(0).GetMarks().SetAngle(90);
works fine but with TeeChart2014.ocx this functionality has stopped working and I am not able to rotate the label to 90 degree.

Please let me know if there is a workaround or the functionality has changed.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with latest *TeeChart2015.ocx*, build 2015.0.0.2? Code below works fine in both VC++ and VB6.

Visual C++:

```
m_ctrlChart.Series(0).GetMarks().SetAngle(90);
```

Visual Basic 6:

```
TChart1.AddSeries scBar
TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues
TChart1.Series(0).Marks.Angle = 90
```